# Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Code:

```
{literal}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form[name='checkout_form']").addClass("cm-ajax");
        $("form[name='checkout_form']").addClass("cm-ajax-full-render");

        $(".ty-value-changer__increase").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
        $(".ty-value-changer__decrease").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
        $(".cm-amount").bind('keyup', function(e) {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings) {
        $("form[name='checkout_form']").addClass("cm-ajax");
        $("form[name='checkout_form']").addClass("cm-ajax-full-render");

        $(".ty-value-changer__increase").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
        $(".ty-value-changer__decrease").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
        $(".cm-amount").bind('keyup', function(e) {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#button_cart').click(); }, 1000);
        });
        var url = settings.url;
        if (url.indexOf("products.options") >= 0) {
            $('#button_cart').click();
        }
    }); 
    </script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: is there any function call on **$('#button_cart').click()** means there is any function call on this?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, i think i might of noticed the issue anyway just checking.

Comment: This is definite that main cause is `$('#button_cart').click();` can you put the functionality of it? just need to confirm before posting any answer.

Comment: Just give me a moment, i think the tpl was missing the top cart buttons which might be causing an issue, just adding them back in and will test and let you know.

Comment: Yep that was the issue all fixed, sorry guys :)

Comment: Can probably be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._